# Macro To Compare Columns And Separate Unique And Duplicate Values

Tags: excel, vba, macos

The requirement is  one macro that can compare two columns of an excel.It should write the unique values which are part of column A and not in column B to one new column 'Unique'.Similarly it has to write duplicate data that are present in both columns to another column 'Duplicate'.

For example if input 'column A' contain A,B,C,D,E and 'column B' contains D,E,F,G,H,I,J
then result column 'Unique' should have  A,B,C and 'Duplicate'  should have D,E.

[Note that number of elements in Column A can be equal, greater or less than column B]

Suggest some method to implement this.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried already? Have you used the macro recorder? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have no background knowledge in creating VBA scripts.

Comment: Try using the macro recorder and record what you do manually and then take a look at the code it produces.

Comment: Manually separating duplicates will not generate any code.

Comment: data - remove duplicates

Comment: data - remove is working only for single column. Here two columns are present. Even if i select both and do remove duplicates nothing is happening.

Comment: Try highlighting duplicates, or googling how to do it. I'm not being snide, but your question is better received [if you put some effort into figuring out what you can](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135049/encouraging-users-to-try-something-before-asking-write-me-code-that-questio). As it stands now, there's 1001 ways to do this which is way too broad.